# Radon transform implementation written in C/C++

Tags: c++, line, transform, detection

I'm searching whether there is an open source C/C++ implementation of Radon Transform. I will try to use it for line detection in images. Most of the image processing libraries (OpenCV) support Hough Transform instead of Radon Transform. But, I read some articles that Radon Transform has better performance than Hough Transform.

I found FTL (Finite Transform Library) and FRTW (Finite Radon Transform Library) as a C/C++ implementation of Radon Transform. But, i could not understand the output of the funtions of the library when compared it MATLAB radon() function. The documentation of FRTW is not so good. In MATLAB, it is easy to use radon() function since it returns directly the Radon Transform of the given image for the given angle range.

Comment: As far as I understand there is not much difference b/w Radon and Hough if used for line detection. Hough Transform is faster that Radon transform; why Radon is better isn't clear to me. Radon Transform is more mathematically sound though.

Comment: In the paper named as "Comparing Hough and Radon transform based parallelogram detection," written by Bhaskar, H. and Werghi, N., two transform is compared for paralelogram detection in the images. They concluded that "experiments comparing the two transforms (Hough/Radon) suggests that the Radon transform based parallelogram detection algorithm is more robust and accurate to the presence of noise when compared to its Hough transform based counterpart".